# iTerm2: Mirror or replay input and output to second window

Tags: shell, console, presentation, iterm, iterm2

I would like to give a tutorial and therefore would like the audience to see my terminal while I am typing, but I am facing the audience and I do NOT want to mirror my screen (I know this would easily solve the problem).

I am also happy to use another program, shell, whatever. Ideally the second console would just be a dumm repeater. It must not repeat the command that I just executed, but just show it.

Do you see a way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use split pane and stretch the window across both monitors, so that one pane is on each monitor, and use `Shell>Broadcast Input`. What you type in the pane on one monitor will be mirrored in the pane on the other.

Unfortunately there isn't a way to do this with two separate windows.

EDIT: the OP commented that this violates the constraint "two screens", apparently having had some difficulty parsing what I was describing. I will attempt to describe it more explicitly:

- there are two *screens*, often also referred to as monitors. One is shining on a wall behind me -- students look at that. One is my laptop *screen*, at which I look.
- I wish to demonstrate something in a terminal. Using the terminal program **iTerm2**, I:

  - use `cmd-N` to create a new window
  - select the menu item `Shell>Split Vertically with Current Profile` to create two panes in the window
  - position the window so that one pane is on the *screen* being projected on the wall at which students look, and the other pane is on my laptop *screen* at which I am looking. This results in one *window* that is being *simultaneously displayed* on two *screens*
  - select the menu item `Shell>Broadcast Input>Broadcast Input to All Panes in Current Tab`

Then, while looking at the pane of the iTerm window which is being displayed on my laptop *screen*, I type shell commands, or code in a programming language in some REPL or other. Through the lovely magic of `Broadcast Input`, everything I type, and the output of every shell command I run (or of some REPL or other) is `simultaneously displayed` in (on?) the *screen* on the wall at which students are diligently looking.

One window. Two screens. iTerm.

Some might legitimately wonder just exactly why I, or the OP, might want to do this rather than just using display mirroring. In my case it is because when I am not demoing things in a terminal I am showing slides in google slides or keynote or some such and wish to view my speaker notes on my laptop while students view only the slides on the projected screen.

Comment: This answer unfortunately violates one of the constraints - two screens

Comment: I do it with two screens. I stretch the two-pane window across two screens so that one pane is on my screen, the other on the presentation screen. I look at and type in the pane I see in my screen. What I type and the output is mirrored in the pane students see. That's what I assumed people would understand from the phrase "stretch the window across both monitors", hopefully this is sufficiently explicit.

Comment: there is one caveat: ctrl-k is not mirrored for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach multiple terminals to a [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) session.  It is simplest if there is only one "window" (so the other terminals are guaranteed to show the same window).  As you type and move around the terminal in your machine, the displays in the other terminals will update to follow it.